# Numpy built in elementwise append

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array 3D array of points onto which I would like to append a corresponding value in a flat array.

```
points = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
info = [1,2]
```

Is there a built in way to append elements from the second array to the corresponding positions in the first?

```
output = [[1,2,3,1],[4,5,6,2]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.hstack`:

```
points = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
info = np.array([1, 2])
output = np.hstack([points, info.reshape(2,1)])
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 1],
       [4, 5, 6, 2]])
```

Comment: ah i was missing the reshape.